# How can i make it work in mongo,somthing like "insert into ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, nosql

The MySQL statement is like:

> insert into t_test(hour, host,hits) valeus('11', 'www.google.com', 12) ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits=hits+12;

What is the statement work in MongoDB?

I use upsert, but what is the code like :hits=hits+12 ? Update a value   based on its current value.

Comment: Read ["upserts"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) in the documentation.

Comment: I use upsert, but what is the code like :hits=hits+12 ?can it  update a value   based on its current value.

Comment: I only see SQL in your question. If you actually "used" something then you should present what you actually tried. But again, you basically seem to be looking for [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/update/inc/)

Comment: You really should read the docs of your selected persistence technology thoroughly. There is a [**`$setOnInsert`** operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#up._S_setOnInsert) in the upsert docs. As a side note: The mindset "I think SQL and translate it to MongoDB" is a good way to get yourself into trouble down the road. Forget SQL, embrace the fact  that you model the data so that your questions get answered in the most efficient way and read the docs **thoroughly**